# SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqlite

hi guys I add this php code

```
<?php $database = new SQLiteDatabase ('ansi.db');    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ansi ORDER BY LIC ";    $result =  $database->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{    echo $row ['LIC'];}?>
```

note :ansi.db size:1200M
but this result

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SQLiteException' with message
>   'SQLiteDatabase::__construct() [sqlitedatabase.--construct]:
>   file is encrypted or is not a database' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlite.php:2 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlite.php(2): SQLiteDatabase->__construct('ansi.db')
>   1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlite.php on line 2

Comment: (a) Is this MySQL or SQLite? You have both tags. (b) You need to include the code that makes the connection, otherwise this is all guess work. (c) Is the database file definitely and SQLite file? This may help to get your question answered.

Comment: So, is it encrypted or not and is it a valid database file?

Comment: You can also get this error if you're using the wrong SQLite version. Example: the db is created with SQLite2 and you're trying to open it with SQLite3 (or the other way arround). Version 2 and 3 are incompatible.

Comment: MySQL PHP ، But .db SQLite > i want use DB in php Xampp plz help me